# Unable to export object to 3ds file

Tags: modeling

I recently downloaded some models from the internet and I'm trying to export them to 3ds files. However, when I'm exporting them, I get an error saying:

```
object %r cannot be exported to a 3ds file
```

And, well, I'm a noob when it comes to blender, so I was wondering if somebody could fix this problem and get the two models exported to 3ds files.

[image: First Model]

This is one of the models. The other one I need exported to a 3ds file is included in the .zip file. (I need both of them exported to a 3ds file.)

You can download the models [here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rycmh37labcxqc1/Dragon%20Statues.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 2):

Your models exceeded the max polygon limit for 3ds files, which is currently 65536. I've decimated the models for you to go below that number. You can download the zip here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mwxzr447792digb/Dragons.zip?dl=0

If you would like a more detailed explanation regarding 3ds exporting please visit this thread:

[Export object to a 3ds file error](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43947/export-object-to-a-3ds-file-error)

Have a nice day!

Comment: Please don't provide a ready made result to the poster, you are doing his work for him and no one learns or benefits from this in the future. Instead explain what you did and why it works preferably with step by step instructions

Answer (score -1):

My solution is to apply Triangulate modifier before exporting.