# object cannot be written into a 3ds file

Tags: export, file-format

I am a rookie user of Blender, my blender project cannot be exported to 3ds file.

How to solve that?

Error message
`Object %r can't be written into a 3DS file`

This is the link of my project [Blender Project 2018](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v6kYEL1YmKP7DHGcKxnoeYeBqGGvNhAG/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43947/export-object-to-a-3ds-file-error https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88976/unable-to-export-object-to-3ds-file  https://blenderartists.org/t/requirements-to-export-as-3ds/581062/8 and when I added a Decimate modifier the resulting loy poly mesh did export to .3ds

Answer (score 2):

There is a maximum number of faces limit with .3ds files. You might be exceeding this. If possible, consider using the .OBJ format, which doesn't have this limitation. Try removing all but a small part of the model and exporting that to confirm if this is your problem.

If it is not this which is causing the problem, try baking all the modifiers before exporting.

Comment: Could you please help me? I want to use my 3D Object into after effect... Thanks in advance...

Comment: I don't use After Effects, but you might consider using the .FBX file export format from Blender. There is a free .FBX import plugin for After Effects. .FBX is a good format for 3D files. Good luck.